# como puedo hacer que los ids dinamicos guardados en mi array se pasen a php y me los guarde en mi bd

Tags: javascript, php, sql, ajax, array

estos dias he estado investigando un poco sobre lo que tengo hacer y a veces me  confundo.
El problema es

"No se como puedo hacer para pasar los ids que tengo en el array a php".

Html:

```
<button type="button" class="boton btn-registrar" id="btnDetalles" >+ Detalles política</button>
```

Js:

```
    $("#btnDetalles").on("click", function () {
    agregarCampos();
    });
```

y al dar click en ese boton me crea un div para llenar unos inputs no importa cuantas veces le de click me crea eso.

```
function agregarCampos() {
cont++;

var categoriaHtml = `
    <div class="titulo">
        <div style="display: flex; justify-content: space-between; align-items: center; margin: 2px 10px 0px 0px;">
            <div id="detalle">
                <span>Detalle # ` + cont + `</span>
            </div>
            <div style="display: flex; align-items: center;">
                <span style="margin: -8px 2px 0px 0px;"><img src="../../iconos/delete.svg" alt="Borrar" class="eliminar-fila img-iconos cursor-pointer limpiarFechafinal"></span>
                <button id="mas" class="btn">
                    <span><img src="../../iconos/Flecha.svg" alt="Borrar" class="bi bi-plus agregar-icon"></span>
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div style="margin: 0px 10px 0px 10px">
            <div class="row row-nomargin mc datospolitica oculto">
                <div class="col-sm-12 modal-subtitle-container b-right">
                    <h3 class="modal-subtitle subtitulos">Categoria</h3>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="text" id="categoriaagregar${cont}" class="form-control imp input-detalle">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row row-nomargin mc datospolitica oculto">
                <div class="col-sm-12 modal-subtitle-container">
                    <h3 class="modal-subtitle subtitulos">Detalle</h3>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="text" id="detalleagregar${cont}" class="form-control imp input-detalle">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>`;

idsArray.push({
    categoria: `categoriaagregar${cont}`,
    detalle: `detalleagregar${cont}`
});

console.log("IDarrays:", idsArray);

$('#container').append(categoriaHtml);
cargarComplemetos2();
cargarComplemetos4();
cargarComplemetos3();
}
```

Esa es la funcion que hace cuando uno da click en el boton.
(No se si el array esta bien.)
El array lo estoy creando al principio de la pagina

```
let cont = 0;
var idsArray = [];
```

tambien le puse un cont = 0 para que los ids incrementen.

Esto es como paso los datos a php on ajax.
No se si la forma que tengo el array esta bien.

```
function validarRegistro() {

const idpoliticacontable = $("#idpoliticacontable").val();
const idempresario = $("#idempresario").val();
const nombreagregar = $("#nombreagregar").val();
const objetivoagregar = tinymce.get("objetivoagregar").getContent();
for (var i = 0; i < idsArray.length; i++) {
const categoriaagregar = $("#" + idsArray[i].categoria).val();
const detalleagregar = tinymce.get(idsArray[i].detalle).getContent();

console.log(categoriaagregar, detalleagregar);
}

var parametros = {accion: AGREGAR_POLITICA, action: true, idpoliticacontable: idpoliticacontable, idempresario: idempresario,
    nombreagregar: nombreagregar, objetivoagregar: objetivoagregar, categoriaagregar: categoriaagregar,
    detalleagregar: detalleagregar};
var miCallback = function (callbackParams, result) {
    if (!result.success) {
        return false;
    }
    jAlert("Datos registrados con éxito.", "Mensaje del Sistema", function () {
        dataTablePolitica.ajax.reload(null, true);
        limpiarFormulario();

    });
};
spinner("Validando Datos, por favor espere...");
utilidadesjQuery.ajax("../contabilidad/PoliticasContables.php", parametros, miCallback, null, this);
}
```

el console.log es para mirar si me esta trayendo los datos y si, al mirar en la consola, me muestra los datos que he llenado en los inputs que cree con el boton.

Y esto ya es lo ultimo

PHP:

```
 protected function administrarPoliticas() {
    $idpoliticacontable = $this->getInt("idpoliticacontable");
    $nombreagregar = $this->getString("nombreagregar");
    $objetivoagregar = $this->getString("objetivoagregar");
    $categoriaagregar = $this->getString("categoriaagregar");
    $detalleagregar = $this->getString("detalleagregar");
    $estado = $this->getString("estado");
    $accion = $this->getBool("action");

    $ultimoId = PoliticaContable::maxIdpoliticaContable();
    $ultimoId++;

    if ($accion === true) {
        $tipoPolitica = new PoliticaContable();
        $tipoPolitica->setNombre($nombreagregar);
        $tipoPolitica->setObjetivo($objetivoagregar);
        $tipoPolitica->setEstado(true);

        $tipoPolitica->guardarObjeto();

        $ultimoId = $tipoPolitica->getIdpoliticacontable();

        $tipoPoliticadetalle = new PoliticaContableDetalle();
        $tipoPoliticadetalle->setIdpoliticacontable($ultimoId);
        $tipoPoliticadetalle->setCategoria($categoriaagregar);
        $tipoPoliticadetalle->setDetalle($detalleagregar);

        $tipoPoliticadetalle->guardarObjeto();

        $descripcionAud = "Se creó la política contable con ID " . $ultimoId . " y nombre: " . $tipoPolitica->getNombre();
    } else {
        $tipoPolitica = PoliticaContable::crear($idpoliticacontable);
        $tipoPolitica->setEstado($estado);
        $tipoPolitica->guardarObjeto();
        $descripcionAud = "Se actualizó la política contable: " . ($estado ? "Activo" : "Inactivo") . " Estado " . $tipoPolitica->getIdpoliticacontable();
    }

    $auditoria = new AuditoriaPrincipal();
    $auditoria->setIdEvento(1103);
    $auditoria->setDescripcion($descripcionAud);
    $auditoria->guardarObjeto();

    $this->retorno->msg = "";
    echo json_encode($this->retorno);
}
```

Si me pueden explicar estaria bien, ya que llevo varios dias intentado hacer eso y me he estresado un poco ya q no me funcionaba
gracias.

estos son los link de que tiene mi codigo

```
        <script src="../../lib/js/vendor/jquery-3.6.1/jquery-3.6.1.js"></script>
        <script src="../../lib/datatables/datatables.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Hola. No has explicado cuál es exactamente el problema con este código. ¿Hay algo que no funciona o da error? ¿Qué es y cuál es el error?

Comment: perdon jajaj, ya lo edite. no vi que no habia agregado el problema

Comment: *No sé si el array está bien*. ¿A qué array te refieres? Imprime dicho array y revisa su estructura, para ver si es conforme a lo que quieres enviar al servidor. *Si me pueden explicar...*, no se entiende qué es lo que quieres que te expliquen... *llevo varios días intentando hacer eso*, ¿intentando hacer qué?

Comment: El array me trae me muestra los datos que quiero, y lo que llevo intentando varios dias es intentar pasar los datos a php.
lo que quiero q me expliquen es como puedo pasar esos datos de js a php, ya he pasado los datos que estan ahi, pero no se es como pasar el array y los datos que tiene dentro

Comment: Para pasar el array a PHP puedes hacerlo con Ajax. Cojes el array y lo metes dentro del parámetro `data` de tu petición Ajax. Te recomiendo que estandarices tu código, pues usas código no estándar, no sé si usas alguna biblioteca en particular que tiene sintaxis como: `utilidadesjQuery.ajax()` ¿?

Comment: Escribe tu petición Ajax según esta estructura: `var request = $.ajax({
  url: "script.php",
  method: "POST",
  data: { id : menuId },
  dataType: "html"
});
 
request.done(function( msg ) {
  $( "#log" ).html( msg );
});
 
request.fail(function( jqXHR, textStatus ) {
  alert( "Request failed: " + textStatus );
});` ahí debes cambiar el valor de `url` por la ruta del archivo php que procesará la petición. Y debes cambiar `data` por un objeto que contenga tu array. Si el servidor responde con un JSON, deberás también cambiar el `dataType` a `json`.

Comment: El bloque de código anterior es [de la documentación de jQuery](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/). Observa que `data` debe ser un objeto estructurado. Supongamos que tienes tu array en una variable llamada `miArray`, pasarás algo así: `data: { allData : miArray }`. En PHP, el array estará dentro de la clave `allData` y lo podrás recuperar haciendo un `$_POST['allData']`.  En `data`, puedes meter más cosas, siempre usando la notación `clave: valor`, debiendo usar en php la notación `$_POST['clave']`, donde `clave` es el dato puesto a la izquierda del elemento declarado en `data` de Ajax.

Comment: Ok, creo q lo entiendo un poco, lo voy a intentar hacer. 
gracias

Comment: Intenta, y si hay cualquier problema, pues **nos dices CUÁL es el problema concretamente**, y si hay algún error lo mismo, nos dices cuál es el error.

Comment: listo, muchas gracias

Comment: Hola ya tengo casi todo, ya solo me falta es hacer un foreach para que me haga el insert dependiendo de cuantos datos hayan.

Comment: Me alegro... Te refieres del lado de PHP, supongo. Pues haz tu `foreach` y haz las inserciones. Y, cuando todo funcione, te recomendaría que uses consultas preparadas, así como transacciones (si es que la configuración de tu tabla soporta esto último) para insertar datos masivos.

Comment: Sí, señor, claro en PHP. Y muchas gracias por la ayuda.

Comment: Mete los id dinamicos en inputs ocultos ... y los puedes recibir de lado del php